# Where should I put a library in a Yii project that is not available via Composer?

Tags: php, yii2

I can't put the library under `vendor/` because that directory is ignored in `.gitignore`. I put it under `bing-ads/` and I have

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

include 'bing-ads\v10\bingads\ClientProxy.php';

use \Yii;
use BingAds\Proxy\ClientProxy;
```

to access it. It works for console commands/actions, but I have a feeling it will not work during a web call because the root directory will be `web/`. Where should I put this library and how can I access it via both console actions and web actions?

The [Microsoft PHP library is located here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Bing-Ads-API-Version-9-in-fb27761f).

Comment: Have you tried? It should work the same.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII But the include path will be different when it is run from the web server.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way by adding the file paths to the `autoload` section of `composer.json`. I remembered that I had to do that for some of the other libraries as well, even the ones available via Composer.

```
"autoload": {
  "classmap": [
    "vendor/googleads/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/Api/Ads/Common/Util",
    "vendor/googleads/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/Api/Ads/AdWords/Util/v201605",
    "bing-ads/v9/bingads/CustomerManagementClasses.php",
    "bing-ads/v10/bingads/v10/CampaignManagementClasses.php",
    "bing-ads/v10/bingads/v10/BulkClasses.php",
    "bing-ads/v10/bingads/ClientProxy.php"
  ]
}
```

Then I ran

```
$ composer install
...
Generating autoload files
```

I'm not sure this is the best way though.

Comment: interesting. I didn't think of this

Answer (score 1):

You could store them wherever you want e.g. in a folder named "BingAds".

Just add the alias as example in a common base config file `/common/config/base.php` which is included in your console as well as in your web application e.g. for your `/web/index.php`

```
$config = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../common/config/base.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../common/config/web.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/base.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php')
);
```

Inside this `common/config/base.php` you could add your settings, extensions etc. which are valid for both the console and your web application

```
<?php
$config = [
    ...
    'aliases' => [
        '@BingAds' => '@app/BingAds/v10',
        '@BingAds/Proxy' => '@app/BingAds/v10/bingads',
    ],
];
```

Your `Clientproxy.php` is stored as example in the directory `/BingAds/Proxy/`.

Then you don't have to include your files every time you want to use them and just write.

```
use BingAds\Proxy\ClientProxy;
```

I have unpacked your linked zip file and stored the files of the directory `Bing Ads API in PHP\PHP\Bing Ads API in PHP` to my application root directory `BingAds` whith the aliases mentioned above.

I have tested it by creating a clientProxy object in both a console and web application.

```
$test = new ClientProxy('test');
var_dump($test);
```

Both Printed out

```
object(BingAds\Proxy\ClientProxy)[140]
  private 'authenticationToken' => null
  private 'username' => null
  private 'password' => null
  private 'developerToken' => null
  private 'wsdlUrl' => string 'test' (length=4)
  private 'accountId' => null
  private 'customerId' => null
  private 'service' => null
  private 'namespace' => null
```

I haven`t tested out other classes but I guess you get how it works.

Comment: I don't have a `common/` directory. This is the contents of my `web/index.php`: http://pastebin.com/EW1UJnHb You can ignore the signal stuff - I was testing something with recycling the servers.

Comment: I just had a "common" directory to store stuff which is for both backend, frontend and console., this was coming from the advanced template.  In my example the configs are stored there.
Of course you can add it to both your console and web config directly.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your composer.json:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "microsoft/bing-ads",
                "version": "9.0.0",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Bing-Ads-API-Version-9-in-fb27761f/file/159208/2/Bing%20Ads%20API%20in%20PHP.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "classmap": [
                        "PHP/Bing Ads API in PHP/v10/bingads/"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],


    "require": {
        "microsoft/bing-ads": "9.0.0"
    }
}
```

Then add composer generated autload.php file if you haven't already.
Then you can call the BingAds\Proxy\ClientProxy() without includes.

There's no better way:)

Answer (score -1):

It's best to place external library to `extensions` directory.

And in config do

```
return [
    'import' => [
        'application.extensions.bing-ads.v10.bingads.ClientProxy',
    ],
    ...
];
```

in main and in console configs.

Comment: That doesn't work. I think you mean `config/web.php`. It gave an error: `Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException

Setting unknown property: yii\web\Application::import`. There is no `import` property: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html

Answer (score -1):

I usually just put the code in a `components` folder. If you're using the basic template, this folder can be under your application root; if you're using the advanced template, this folder can be under the necessary app: frontend, backend, console, or common. I recommend putting it under common for reasons I shall explain later

Under every app config, Yii 2 uses the `::setAlias` method to assign different aliases to the key folders. In the basic app template, `@app` refers to the application root. While in the advanced template `@app` may refer to any of backend, frontend, or console.

If your library code is under backend, you can access it like so

```
namespace backend\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;
use backend\components\MyLibCode;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $mlb = new MyLibCode();
        // ...
    }
}
```

However, it is good Yii 2 practice to have common library code in the `common` folder. So if this library code is to be used across apps, I suggest you put it into the `common\components` folder and replace `backend` with `common` in the `use` statement in the code above.

p.s: [Justinas method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38627717/393021) also works; it's borrowed from Yii 1. But this may become cumbersome because this asks Yii to load the class when the application starts. If there is some heavy-lifting in that file, it may be detrimental to the app's performance.

Comment: Ok I moved the folder to `components\bing-ads` and commented out the `include()` lines and added `component\ ` to all `use` lines, but it gave an error: `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'components\BingAds\v10\CampaignManagement\MatchType' not found in /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/bestsales/models/BingAds.php on line 413`. Where are the files being included? How does PHP know about the classes?

Comment: And why would the file path have anything to do with the namespace used? Why would I need to add `components\ ` to the namespace just because it is in that directory?

Comment: Yii 2 tries to be PSR-4 compliant. This is thy the namespaces and the file paths should correspond.

Comment: OK but there are different home directories when it is run as a web app and when it is run as a console command. When it runs as a web app, the current directory is `web/`, and when it runs as a console command, the current directory is the project home directory. You still have to use `include()` or `require()` somewhere, and specify a path. It's not like Java where the JVM itself checks the file system when you use `import`.

Comment: if the namespaces are properly specified in the library — and by "properly specified" I mean "PSR-4 compliant" — then you should not need to use `require` or `include`; `use` will suffice. And once they are in any folder in the Yii app structure, they can be referenced properly. However, if these libraries are not compliant with PSR-4, then you will need to include.

Comment: I doubt they are compliant. They are from Microsoft. I can't use just the namespace because they are in a folder named `bing-ads/` and you can't use dashes in a `use` statement. I tried.